# Does Mongrel do IPv6 well?

Tags: apache, mongrel, ipv6, mongrel-cluster

I'm using 
mongrel + apache 2.2 + mod_proxy_balancer.

apache2.2 is IPv6 well
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html#ipv6

Does Mongrel do IPv6 well?

Platform:RHEL
ruby:1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache as a frontend to Mongrel, whether Mongrel supports IPv6 or not is irrelevant, as Apache will serve your requests over IPv6 anyway.

It is perfectly acceptable to have Apache listen on `[::]:80`, and proxy to a Mongrel running on `127.0.0.1:1234`, or whatever you use, and will be no less ‘IPv6-ready’ than proxying to a Mongrel running on, say `[::1]:1234`.

The `127.0.0.1` loopback interface will not be going anywhere any time soon, even after the [apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion)!

Comment: Does Mongrel track anything by IP address?  Won't it get confused by this solution if it does?

Comment: That sort of confusion would occur whether over IPv4 or IPv6, thus isn't quite relevant to this question.

Using Apache as a reverse proxy in this way is the norm (and is a safe assumption that the O.P. is doing it this way).